# canvas - pinch zooming using by fabricjs and angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying pinch zoom on canvas using **FabricJs**.  but i  have no idea about that.

And i also searched some  codes from google. But not work. any one does not  write a article for zooming option using fabric.

Please if you have any idea about that. please let me know.......

I  have tried this

....

```
canvas.on('touch:gesture', function (e) {
                isGestureEvent = true;
                // /* Just use the scale of the touch event to determine zoom in or zoom out. */
                var lPinchScale = e.self.scale;
                var type = e.e.type;
                if (type == "touchstart") {

                    //console.log("touchstart");
                    aGestureTouchStartTouches = e.e.touches;
                    aGestureScale.push(lPinchScale);
                    //console.log("scale:" + lPinchScale);

                } else if (type == "touchmove") {
                    console.log("touchmove");


                    //var modCheck = 5;
                    //if(aGestureScale.length % modCheck == 0) {

                    // canvasScale is current scale
                    // lPinchScale is what we want to set it to, relative to what it is now
                    // ie if canvasScale == 2.7
                    // var newScale = canvasScale * lPinchScale
                    // newScale is where we want canvasScale to end up
                    // 

                    // Get the last pinch scale;
                    var lastScale = aGestureScale[aGestureScale.length - 1];

                    // if scaleDiff negative then pinch in (zoom out), positive it is pinch out (zoom in)
                    var scaleDiff = lPinchScale - lastScale;
                    if (scaleDiff < 0) {

                        scaleDiff = lastScale - lPinchScale;
                        scaleDiff = 1 + scaleDiff;
                        fnZoomOutByFactor(scaleDiff);
                    }
                    else {

                        scaleDiff = 1 + scaleDiff;
                        fnZoomInByFactor(scaleDiff);
                    }

                    //console.log("scale:" + lPinchScale);
                    //}

                    // add new scale
                    aGestureScale.push(lPinchScale);

                } else {
                    console.log("gesture that is not move or start")
                }
            });
```

....

It's just like a sample code.  I can't put my all code. bcs that's very large code.. Please provide some sample for me..

Thanks!!

I have downloaded  the latest version : https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/tags

But Not working. :(

Comment: Is your event firing at all?

Answer (score 5):

I changed a little and it work

```
var canvas = new fabric.CanvasWithViewport('canvas');
canvas.on('touch:gesture',function(event){
    isGestureEvent = true;      
    var lPinchScale = event.self.scale;  
    var scaleDiff = (lPinchScale -1)/10 + 1;  // Slow down zoom speed    
    canvas.setZoom(canvas.viewport.zoom*scaleDiff);   

});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need a custom build with the gestures module: http://fabricjs.com/build/

When using this the gesture events should be triggered.